# Send e-mail from admin area to adresses in custom field

Tags: pages, email

My client wants to be able to send an e-mail from the Page Editing Screen to a number of e-mail addresses. Every page has a custom field called  *email_addresses* that takes comma seperated addresses:

[image]

Every page will have a different set of addresses. I need a textarea below this field in which my client can enter the body of the email and a submit button below that to actually send the email.

I've added a form with a textarea and a submit form to the Page Editing Screen page using the `add_meta_box()` function:

```
    // Add metabox
    function metabox_after_publish() {
       add_meta_box( 'send-email', 'Send E-mail', 'send_email_metabox_content', 'page', 'advanced', 'high' );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'metabox_after_publish' );

    // callback function to populate metabox
    function send_email_metabox_content() { ?>
        <form>
             <textarea id="email_content" style="width:100%" rows="6"></textarea>
             <p><input id="email_send_button" type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Send" /></p>
        </form>
    <?php }
```

[image]

How can I make the form function so it sends the content of the textarea to the email addresses in the custom field?

Comment: you need a plugin to do this. do you know how to do a plugin ?

Comment: I do but  I could use some pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide us with some information on what you have tried yourself so far, where you're at, what's working and what isn't. We're not going to do your work for you :-).

Comment: I've updated the question. All the nessecary elements (custom field with email addresses, textarea and submit button) are now on the page. It just needs to be tied together. Unfortunately I lack the kowledge to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, decide [whether you want to use GET or POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) for your form. (without specifying the method, it will use GET.)

You will need the `name` attribute filled out for your textarea, so the info can actually be sent. Then add your form processing into your function:

(i.e. `if ( isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["message"]) ) {...}` )

You will need to use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email_addresses' )` to retrieve the email addresses from the custom field. Store that value in a string variable. You will want to [separate out the email addresses into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php) *(beware of the space - you should make sure your client knows if they should or shouldn't have a space after the commas)*.

Then, you'll need to loop through the array with a `foreach`, (because the PHP `mail()` function's `$to` parameter does not accept arrays, only strings). You can build out your email form processing like [the examples on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need any clarification.